# How can I tell if modelling/testing with Binomial/Beta is correct?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, beta-distribution

My standard disclaimer:  I'm a programmer, not a stats guy, mostly wanting to understand statistical tests for optimizing web apps.

Let's say I want to measure monetization rate of users.  "How many users monetize?".  This is a yes/no question on each user.

After reading Wikipedia, I might say, "This yes/no question is a Bernoulli variable.  I can model groups of users as instances of the Binomial distribution, and use Binomial and Beta distributions to estimate *p* and compare the groups of users."

But, what if *p* is not the same for every user in the group?  Some users will always monetize, some users will never monetize...  Some will monetize after their next payday.

Even though the question is a yes/no question, is it sometimes wrong (or rather, how safe is it) to use Binomial/Beta distributions to model a collection this way?  These distributions assume a constant *p*, but when *p* might vary for each user am I getting incorrect results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A heterogeneous mixture of $p$'s will make a single-$p$ binomial model have the wrong variance structure.

A beta-binomial model allows for a (beta-) distribution of $p$'s and then conditional on $p$, a binomial (specifically bernoulli) distribution of individual responses. If I was taking a Bayesian approach this would be my first thought.

If you have good predictors of the $p$'s you might consider a GLM, so that conditionally the distribution is binomial and the model for the mix of $p$'s is determined by the predictors in the model.

Outside of that, and in a more general class of models, you might consider random effects models, specifically GLMs with random effects.